# Cannot DROP FUNCTION because it is being referenced by object

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got this error while trying to drop some User Defined Functions.

```
Msg 3729, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Cannot DROP FUNCTION 'dbo.testfn2' because it is being referenced by object 'testtable2'.

Msg 3729, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Cannot DROP FUNCTION 'dbo.testfn' because it is being referenced 
by object 'DF__testtable__idc__5CD6CB2B'.
```

One reason for this error was 
some columns were using the function in their **default constraints**.

I tried removing all default constraints.

But there are reasons other than this.

What are the other possibilities?

Comment: Well...if you try to drop it what objects does it say are referencing it? You can also check out SQL Search from redgate, it is a free tool that may help with this and a zillion other things.

Comment: It was in computed columns. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show dependencies you can use [`sp_depends`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) procedure:

```
exec sp_depends 'dbo.YourFunc'
```

Or, call [sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referencing-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) table valued function:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('dbo.YourFunc','OBJECT')
```

Answer (score 2):

There were two scenarios in my case. The specified functions were used by

```
1. A Column for its default value
2. A Computed Column for its value calculation
```

**Case 1 :**

The Default Constraints can be viewed from sys.default_constraints

```
 SELECT * FROM sys.default_constraints
```

We can drop the default constraint by

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP CONSTRAINT DF__tableName_ConstraintName
```

After removing all usage of this Function as default constraint, we can drop the function by

```
DROP FUNCTION schemaName.fnName
```

**Case 2 :**

We can see the computed columns from sys.computed_columns

```
 SELECT * FROM sys.computed_columns
```

For my purpose, it was OK to DROP the computed columns which uses the specified functions.

We can drop a column by

```
ALTER TABLE schema.tableName DROP COLUMN columnName
```

After removing all the computed columns using this function , we can drop it as we did earlier.